# repetitive values even with the usage of Distinct key word with inner join

Tags: mysql, inner-join, distinct

student table.

| regno | name | lname | address |gender | mobile |

booking table

bookID | regno | tokenNo | CheckIn    | CheckOut

I am trying to get the no.of female students present between two given dates. I have tried to get the respective values but it outputs repetitive values as well even with the distinct keyword.
I have also tried to use Union and still it does the right opposite of distinct.

```
 SELECT  count(gender) FROM (SELECT  distinct regno from student where 
 gender = 'Male' union  SELECT Distinct regno from book)  x  LEFT OUTER JOIN 
 student a on x.regno = a.regno LEFT OUTER JOIN book b on x.regno = b.regno
  where checkIn >= '2015/7/23' AND checkOut <= '2015/7/31';
```

this is the other I have tried

```
 SELECT count(gender) FROM (SELECT  distinct(regno), gender from student
   where  gender = 'Male' ) AS A inner JOIN book AS B On A.regno = B.regno            
    where   checkIn >= '2015/7/23' AND checkOut <= '2015/7/31';
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are over-complicating a simple query. All you need to do is join the tables and filter on date and gender and apply count.

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT s.regno) 
FROM student s
JOIN booking b on s.regno = b.regno
WHERE s.gender = 'Female' 
  AND b.checkIn >= '2015/7/23' AND b.checkOut <= '2015/7/31';
```

The `distinct` keyword makes sure each student is only counted once if the have multiple bookings in the period. If you want to count all bookings just remove the `distinct`.